# Ghost4J - EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (JVM is crashing)

Tags: java, ghost4j

I'm trying to replace the PDF converter we are using in the company, but I'm getting this issue with Ghost4J. Note my code is very similar to the sample they provide...

I'm using Java SE 1.6 (jrockit-jre1.6.0_33-R28.2.4) and Ghostscript 9.10 for Win 64 bits.

My code is:

```
public void convertPostScriptToPDF() {
        File file= new File (this.getClass().getResource( "/resources/employer_report_last_page.ps").getFile());
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try{

            //load PostScript document
            PSDocument document = new PSDocument();
            document.load(file);        

            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("rendition.pdf"));    
            //create converter
            PDFConverter converter = new PDFConverter();

            //set options
            converter.setPDFSettings(PDFConverter.OPTION_PDFSETTINGS_PREPRESS);

            //convert
            converter.convert(document, fos);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally{
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(fos);
        }
    }
```

The JVM crash, that occurs on "converter.convert(document, fos);" displays on the dump file the message:

```
Error Message: Illegal memory access. [54]
Exception Rec: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (00000000c0000005) at 0x0000000067ECE347 - memory at 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF could not be read.
Minidump     : Wrote mdmp. Size is 650MB
SafeDllMode  : -1
Version      : Oracle JRockit(R) R28.2.4-14-151097-1.6.0_33-20120618-1634-windows-x86_64
CPU          : Intel  SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 Intel64**strong text**
Number CPUs  : 4
Tot Phys Mem : 4110749696 (3920 MB)
OS version   : Microsoft Windows 7 version 6.1 Service Pack 1 (Build 7601) (64-bit)
Thread System: Windows Threads
Java locking : Lazy unlocking enabled (class banning) (transfer banning)
State        : JVM is running
Command Line : -Xms=512m -Xmx=512m -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -Dsun.java.command=org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner -version 3 -port 57292 -testLoaderClass org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader -loaderpluginname org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime -test au.edu.nsw.det.reportgenerator.business.ReportManagerTest:convertPostScriptToPDF -Dsun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner -version 3 -port 57292 -testLoaderClass org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader -loaderpluginname org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime -test au.edu.nsw.det.reportgenerator.business.ReportManagerTest:convertPostScriptToPDF
Repository   : 
java.home    : C:\Program Files\Java\jrockit-jre1.6.0_33-R28.2.4
j.class.path : C:\EmployerReportGenerator\bin;C:\EmployerReportGenerator\lib\emp-model.jar;C:\EmployerReportGenerator\lib\ghost4j-0.5.0.jar;C:\EmployerReportGenerator\lib\commons-io-1.3.1.jar;C:\EmployerReportGenerator\lib\jna-platform-4.0.0.jar;C:\EmployerReportGenerator\lib\log4j-1.2.15.jar;C:\EmployerReportGenerator\lib\xmlgraphics-commons-1.4.jar;C:\EmployerReportGenerator\lib\commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar;C:\EmployerReportGenerator\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\EmployerReportGenerator\lib\itext-2.1.7.jar;C:\EmployerReportGenerator\lib\jna-3.3.0.jar;C:\projects\det\lib\jasperreports-1.2.8.jar;C:\projects\det\release\PDFGeneratorService-client-1.0.jar;C:\TBO\DependentJars\ojdbc14.jar;C:\oracle\oc4j10.1.3.2\j2ee\home\applib\rdbthin.jar;C:\projects\det\release\xmlCommon-1_0.jar;C:\projects\det\release\jet-3_0.jar;C:\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\797\1\.cp\lib\j2ee-1.3\ejb-api.jar;C:\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\797\1\.cp\lib\j2ee-1.3\jca-api.jar;C:\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\797\1\.cp\lib\j2ee-1.3\jms-api.jar;C:\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\797\1\.cp\lib\j2ee-1.3\jsp-api.jar;C:\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\797\1\.cp\lib\j2ee-1.3\jta-api.jar;C:\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\797\1\.cp\lib\j2ee-1.3\servlet-api.jar;C:\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\797\1\.cp\lib\j2ee-1.3\sql-api.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.junit_4.10.0.v4_10_0_v20120426-0900\junit.jar;C:\eclipse\plugins\org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar;C:\projects\det\lib\commons-logging-1.1.jar;/C:/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/346/1/.cp/;/C:/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/979/1/.cp/
j.lib.path   : C:\Program Files\Java\jrockit-jre1.6.0_33-R28.2.4\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\app\tfirmino\product\11.2.0\client_1;C:\app\tfirmino\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\GTK\2.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\cvsnt;C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer;C:\Program Files (x86)\SSH Communications Security\SSH Secure Shell;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\Shared\PowerBuilder\;C:\Program Files (x86)\SSH Communications Security\SSH Secure Shell;C:\Users\thais.firmino\Application Data\SSH\UserKeys;C:\Python27;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin;;.
JAVA_HOME    : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\
_JAVA_OPTIONS: <not set>
PATH         : C:\app\tfirmino\product\11.2.0\client_1;C:\app\tfirmino\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\GTK\2.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\cvsnt;C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer;C:\Program Files (x86)\SSH Communications Security\SSH Secure Shell;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\Shared\PowerBuilder\;C:\Program Files (x86)\SSH Communications Security\SSH Secure Shell;C:\Users\thais.firmino\Application Data\SSH\UserKeys;C:\Python27;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin;
StackOverFlow: 0 StackOverFlowErrors have occured
OutOfMemory  : 0 OutOfMemoryErrors have occured
C Heap       : Good; no memory allocations have failed
GC Strategy  : Mode: throughput, with strategy: genparpar (basic strategy: genparpar)
GC Status    : OC is not running. Last finished OC was OC#0.
             : YC is not running. Last finished YC was YC#0.
```

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance,
Thais

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts is that my issue is related in someway to UAC on windows OS as mentioned on http://www.java.com/en/download/help/exception_access.xml, but changing as suggested didn't solve the issue.
Anyway, through a workaround I got my issue solved. See below I'm using the core API instead of the high level one:

```
public void convert() {

        //get Ghostscript instance
        Ghostscript gs = Ghostscript.getInstance();

        File file= new File (this.getClass().getResource( "/resources/employer_report_last_page2.ps").getFile());//(Config.EMP_REPORT.REPORT_LAST_PAGE_STORE_PATH);
       // File file= new File (this.getClass().getResource( "/resources/Issues.ps").getFile());

        //prepare Ghostscript interpreter parameters
        //refer to Ghostscript documentation for parameter usage
        String[] gsArgs = new String[10];
        gsArgs[0] = "-ps2pdf";
        gsArgs[1] = "-dNOPAUSE";
        gsArgs[2] = "-dBATCH";
       gsArgs[3] = "-dSAFER";
        gsArgs[4] = "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite";
        gsArgs[5] = "-sOutputFile=output2.pdf";//output file name
       // gsArgs[5] = "-sOutputFile=" + file.getAbsolutePath();
        gsArgs[6] = "-c";
        gsArgs[7] = ".setpdfwrite";
        gsArgs[8] = "-f";
       // gsArgs[9] = "input.ps";//input file name
        gsArgs[9] = file.getAbsolutePath();//input file name

        //execute and exit interpreter
        try {

            gs.initialize(gsArgs);               
            gs.exit();

        } catch (GhostscriptException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

public synchronized void convertPostScriptToPDF()

or

public void convertPostScriptToPDF() {
    synchronized(this) {
        ...
    }
}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.